# Understanding values of variable importance of Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

As far as I understand, the mean decreased accuracy of a variable is calculated in each tree recording the out of bag error of the variable and subtracting the out of bag error for the same sample used to construct the three but with the values of the variable permuted, then the differences across all trees are averaged and divided between the its standard deviation.

Let's use as an example the iris data:

```
> iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE)
> importance(iris.rf)
                setosa versicolor virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length  6.116697  7.5435799  7.778538            10.613957         9.794883
Sepal.Width   4.164530  0.2126826  5.441507             4.765478         2.466190
Petal.Length 22.008324 34.2143904 28.077054            34.708242        43.264116
Petal.Width  22.593229 31.8538872 32.629733            33.842020        43.715771
```

So, what is the interpretation for the values of response variable? I guess that it's the same interpretation of mean decrease accuracy but just for the values of the response variable, in this case "setosa" , "versicolor" and virignica". I read the documentation of the `randomForest` package and didn't find any explanation about that point.

Comment: This might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736514/r-random-forests-variable-importance

Comment: Class specific variable importance is explained here:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164569/interpreting-output-of-importance-of-a-random-forest-object-in-r/164585#164585